# Xamarin iOS Navigation Bar 2 Buttons Right Side

Tags: button, xamarin.ios, navbar

I need to have 2 buttons on Navigator bar
1 for Settings and 1 For Sorting

I tried setting right button but it only sets one button

Any suggestions, how could i achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `UIBarButtonItem` into `NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems`. For example:

```
var button1 = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play);
var button2 = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add);
NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems = new UIBarButtonItem[] { button1, button2 };
```

I'm using system defined `UIBarButtonItem`, you can create your own button and add into the array.